# How to load an external javascript file asynchronously within popup.html?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I've got everything working, but after adding an external javascript file (which is, by the way, only a couple of short lines in length), it delays loading of the popup.html.

This delay is annoying, and I think by asynchronously loading the javascript file, then it will get rid of this lag.

The file is written in popup.html like this:

`<script src="https://domain.com/myexternalscript.js"></script>`

I'm not sure how to asynchronously load this file. So how can I do this?

Comment: did you add this reference to master page of your site or just to popup.html page?

Comment: It's only on the popup.html page.

Comment: How big is the java script file? if that is something small, add it in your main page?

Comment: Tiny. Just a couple of lines. _(Also it's impossible to add the javascript inline on a Chrome Extension popup.html. Google disabled inline javascript ability.)_

Answer (score 1):

Since you are developing for Chrome, I do understand the problem with inlining a script before load.
I wrote this AJAX(jQuery) snippet, hope you'll find it usefull:

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "GET", //or post?
            url: "http://FOOBAR.COM",   //change the url obviously..
            datatype: "script", //identify the expected income 
            async: "true", //async is "true" by default, but let's make sure it's #t
            success: function(result) {
                /**now we append the script to the document, nothing too special,
                   just pay attention we inject it INSIDE the item and not as the src**/
                var scr = document.createElement('script');
                scr.innerHTML = result;
                document.body.appendChild(scr)

            },
            error: function(result) { 
            //a simple error handling using the same method we used for the success
                console.log(result) 
                var scr = document.createElement('script');
                scr.innerHTML = "alert('ERROR!')";
                document.body.appendChild(scr)
            }

       });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1. Move the script tag to the end of the html page.
2. Use the `defer` attribute on the script tag, which, however, is not supported by older browsers.

Comment: Let me try. --- update: I added the defer attribute and moved the script to the end of the page, but no difference, still delay.

Comment: Not only that, but adding the defer tag made the script non-functional.

Answer (score 0):

The delay could be because the source is a secure http (https) request, instead of just a plain-vanilla http request. Depending on your particular hosting plan, this may or may not make a difference. Arguments and evidence have been made and presented to support this notion and the contrary.

I don't think loading the file asynchronously will solve your problem, because you would be making the same http request... which is what AJAX does; It allows us to request information from the server without reloading the page.

If it's just a couple lines of JS, then why not just include it in your .html document?

Also, you haven't described issue that you are encountering very well. Perhaps you can elaborate?

Comment: It needs to be external. This way I can manually update it OUTSIDE the extension. Not only that, but it's IMPOSSIBLE to use inline javascript within popup.html since Google has disabled this ability without recourse. /// The issue is that there is a delay when clicking the popup button for the extension in Google Chrome. I was hoping that if I could load the popup BEFORE running the external script (and hence, BEFORE making the http request), then I was hoping that it would eliminate the delay.

Comment: p.s. you're right that it's the http(s) request that is causing the delay, and not the size of the javascript file. This is why I am hoping to delay script execution until after page load.

Comment: ANd by the way, it MUST be httpS. IT is required in order to access external javascript file in popup.html. YOu can't use normal http otherwise I would.